# How to link category list item to an external link in Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I've encountered a problem. I need to link one of my list items in my category menu to an external website. I've searched the net and there were some issues with similiar problem and the answers were to simply put them in manualy into /header.tpl/ - this is where my problem begins - my /header.tpl looks different then default (I'm using a template).

This is it:

```
        <?php if ($categories) { ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="menu-gadget" class="menu-gadget" >
                <?php if ($categories_tm) {
                    echo $categories_tm;
                } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($categories) { ?>
    <div id="stuck" class="stuck-menu">
        <div id="tm_menu" class="nav__primary">
            <div class="container">
                <?php if ($categories_tm) {
                    echo $categories_tm;
                } ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

It seems like it's using some category_tm module so I looked for it but this module is not even installed.

I also searched for such an option in admin panel in given category, but there is option available like that.

What to do ? Thanks for help guys.

link: http://eufrazia.sk/site/index.php?route=common/home

Comment: mistakes were made:

I also searched for such an option in admin panel in given category, but there is >NO< option available like that.

Answer (score 0):

$categories_tm is variable from /catalog/controller/common/header.php. You should edit this variable. Can you paste code where $categories_tm is initialized?